# Google Map crashes when I try to get user device location

Tags: android, google-maps

So I am trying to get the device location to show up on my map following this guide: [googlemaps doc](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current#java)

I put in the code to my activity and was able to get it all set up with no errors. When I go to run the project however my map has been crashing. I think my problem lies with where I put the code in the onMapReady function. I am also unsure if I need to do something speical with "if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != Package..."

Any advice would be great!

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.location.Location;

import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;


public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {


    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationClient;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));



        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        }
        LatLng temp = new LatLng(fusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().getResult().getLatitude()
                , fusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().getResult().getLongitude());

        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(temp).title("Marker in Home"));

    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the stack trace of the crash

Comment: The `getLastLocation()` call may return `null` which then results in a `NullPointerException`. Request location updates to receive an up-to-date location.

Comment: Check `logcat` output

Answer (score 0):

```
   if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    }
       //This means that you do not have permission to access the person's location information, so, you need to request the permissions

   } else {

        LatLng temp = new LatLng(fusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().getResult().getLatitude()
            , fusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().getResult().getLongitude());

        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(temp).title("Marker in Home"));

   }
```